# How to setup global CORS in Hapi.js using Glue

Tags: cors, hapi.js

I was able to setup CORS in Hapi.js on the level of individual route configuration, however, it doesn't work when I use the same configuration on the server level. According to the Hapi.js API documentation, the following should work, but it doesn't. I use Glue to setup my server - this is my configuration Glue snippet:

```
...
"connections": [
  {
    "host": "0.0.0.0",
    "port": 8000,
    "routes": {
      "cors": {
        "origin": ["*"],
        "additionalHeaders": ["cache-control", "x-requested-with"]
      }
    }
  }
]
...
```

Any idea why this doesn't work?

When I put the `cors` section directly into individual route configurations, it works:

```
exports.list = {
  id: 'topicList',
  cors: {
    origin: ['*'],
    additionalHeaders: ['cache-control', 'x-requested-with']
  },
  handler: function(request, reply) {
    Models.Topic.findAll((err, topics) => {
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

How about putting the `routes` configuration in the `server` attribute of the Glue configuration?

```
server: {
    connections: {
        routes: {
            cors: {
                origin: ['*'],
                additionalHeaders: ['headers']
            }
        }
    }
},
connections: [
    ...
]
...
```